# MYSQL to POSTGRESQL via SED

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Estou buscando uma forma de migrar meu backup de um banco em Mysql para Postgresql. A forma mais simples que encontrei foi usando sed em cima do backup, mas não tem dado certo.

Foi da seguinte forma:

1 - efetuando um backup

2 - executando o comando `sed "s/\\\'/\'\'/g" bkp-bancodedados.sql`

3 - importando o backup no postgresql com o comando `psql databasename < bkp-bancodedados.sql`

[Como informado nesse link](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/15556/postgresql/migrando-mysql-para-postgresql?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Porém ao tentar importar o backup não funciona, por erros de sintaxe. Acredio que o sed nao está sendo executado corretamente, ou então eu deveria subistituir as aspas, não sei. Alguém consegue me ajudar, por favor?

Um dos erros é o seguinte:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `destinatario_mensagem` VALUES (147799,52350,NUL...
```

Comment: substituindo as crases por aspas simples deve funcionar

Comment: Esse projeto te ajuda?
https://github.com/AnatolyUss/FromMySqlToPostgreSql

Comment: Eu gostaria de algo mais simples. E o que tinha encontrado mais simples era esse sed

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `mysqldump` com a opção `--compatible`.

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql dbname > export.sql
```

Em seguida, você precisa escapar as aspas do arquivo gerado com o comando `sed`. Utilize o seguinte comando para escapar as aspas no arquivo **export.sql** e salvar o arquivo **novo_export.sql** com as alterações

```
sed "s/\\\'/\'\'/g" export.sql > novo_export.sql
```

*(Repare que no código que você está executando, a saída do comando `sed` não está sendo gravada no arquivo e dessa forma você está tentando importar o mesmo arquivo gerado pelo `mysqldump`).*

Em seguida você pode importar o novo arquivo gerado pelo `sed` utilizando o `psql`.

```
psql databasename < novo_export.sql
```

Comment: Na hora de importar com o `psql` occoreu o seguinte erro: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   "id_mytable" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`

Comment: Tem alguma ideia do que pode solucionar?